# How to load module in my own created library codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
 class Mylib
 {
    function show_lib()
    {

       $obj=& get_instance();
       $obj->load->module(‘login_check’);
       $var=$obj->login_check->get_all_table_data();
       print_r($var);
    }
 }
```

ERROR:-
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::module()

Answer (score 1):

I Hope This Will Work --> check this code

```
class Mylib
{   
  function show_lib()
  {
      protected $ci; 
     $this->ci = &get_instance();
     $this->ci->load->library(‘login_check’);
     $var=ci->load->login_check->get_all_table_data();     
     return $var;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not module, it's a library

use:

```
$this->load->library();
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with modules in CI is called HMVC - Hierarchical Model View Controller.
There is a beautiful modular extension for CI to work with - [Modular Extensions - HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/overview)

By using this extension you can create and work with modules in CI.

After setting up HMVC Extension you can call modules from your controller.

```
$controller = $this->load->module('module_name/controller_name');
echo $controller->method();
```

Few tutorials to get started:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/
http://www.extradrm.com/blog/?p=744

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeigniter 3 you need to use Codeigniter Object to load modules,helpers..etc. Assign Codeigniter object to a variable and use it. `$CI =& get_instance()` Sample code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CustomLibrary{

    public $random_number;

    public function __construct(){

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->helper('string');
    }
}
```

For more information about this visit http://www.webnsyntax.com/